# how to increment a count every seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to develop a stopwatch,But i have problem increment my count using for and while statement please can somebody tel me where am going and help me fix my code,my problem is that once after the interval of time i set it increment from 1 to 10 at one second but i want it to add one every one second.

```
var count=0;
var s = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    while(count < 10){
    $("#mi").html(count);
        count++;
    }
},1000);

//i also use for but both give did same thing
setInterval(function(){
    for(count=0;count < 10;count++){
        $("#mi").html(count);
    }
},1000);

<div id="mi">0</div>
```

Comment: An interval is something that happens over and over and over so you do not need the loop inside the interval.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`clearInterval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) to break timer.

> The clearInterval() method clears a timer set with the setInterval()
>   method.
>
> The ID value returned by setInterval() is used as the parameter for
>   the clearInterval() method.

So try this:

```js
    var count=0;
    var tHnd = setInterval(function(){
       if(count == 10)
           clearInterval(tHnd); 
       $("#mi").html(count);
       count++;
    },1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mi"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below works. Why do want to use a loop ? If the point is to increment it by one every second do this :

```
var count=0;
setInterval(function()
{
  console.log(count++);
},1000);
```

if you want to increment it by 10 then this

```
var count=0;
setInterval(function()
{
  console.log(count += 10);
},1000);
```